# Key string-array expected String[] but value was a java.util.ArrayList

Tags: android, android-intent, arrays

Im new to android.

how to get the array values from one class to another class using Intent??

I tried like this...
1st activity...

> ```
>  Intent videointent = new Intent(Focusarea.this,Videoplayer.class);
>  videointent.putExtra("string-array", resim_list);
>  startActivity(videointent);
> ```

2nd activity

> ```
>      Intent intent=getIntent();
>     String [] Array = intent.getStringArrayExtra("string-array");
> ```

Im getting this as warning and im getting null as the value in 2nd second activity..

> ```
>      W/Bundle(521): Key string-array expected String[] but value was a 
>      java.util.ArrayList.  The default value <null> was returned.
>      W/Bundle(521): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
>      W/Bundle(521): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList
>      W/Bundle(521):     at android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(Bundle.java:1459)
>      W/Bundle(521):     at 
>      android.content.Intent.getStringArrayExtra(Intent.java:3630)
>       W/Bundle(521):    at 
>      com.example.TEENEINSTIEN.Videoplayer.onCreate(Videoplayer.java:20)
>       W/Bundle(521):    at 
>       android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("string-array", resim_list);
videointent.putExtras(bundle);
```

than in `Videoplayer` Activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String [] myStringArray = bundle.getStringArray("string-array");
```

Edit: in the question is a bit unclair if `resim_list` in a `String[]` or an `ArrayList`.
If `resim_list` is an `ArrayList`

```
bundle.putStringArrayList("string-array", resim_list);
```

to store it and

```
 bundle.getStringArrayList("string-array")
```

to retrieve it

Comment: with startActivity. As usual.

Comment: is resim_list  a String array?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `resim_list` instance is an ArrayList

You should store a String[] with :

```
videointent.putExtra("string-array", resim_list.toArray(new String[resim_list.size()]));
```

Comment: While printing in logcat i get like this  String Video[Ljava.lang.String;@40709f38